# increasing the size of header of window

Tags: smartgwt

I want to increase the size of header of smartgwt.Window and insert the my own logo into the header of Window. like smartGWT Showcase windows (green color diamond with title). please see the image

Thanks in advance [window custom header icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LAsY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the header icon with the following code:

```
String iconLocation = "/testcases/resources/images/logo.png"; 
window.setHeaderIcon(iconLocation, 16, 16);
```

Regarding the height, I [don't think](http://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a/26824-change-header-height-for-a-window?p=176172#post176172) it is possible without [skinning](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-release/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Skinning.html) SmartGWT, and that is not a trivial task. Besides, it could even hurt your L&F if you don't modify all the `Window`'s header elements to accommodate to the new height. Unless this is a non-refusable requirement, I would suggest you use an icon that fits in the 20px header height.